# How can i make the responsive design using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float, responsive-design

How can i make the responsive design when i view from smartphone or tablet. It should align properly and show the exact output in any device.Here is the code that i tried to implement in popup. I am Not sure How to make it as responsive based on the css. Any suggestion would be great.

```
      <div id="ptechsolfb">
          <div id="fb-close"></div>
            <div id="ptechsolfblike">
              <div id="fbclose"></div>
              <div id="ptechsolinside">
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <style type="text/css">
            #ptechsolinside {
              background-image:url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
              }
             #ptechsolfblike {width:500px;height:500px; position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-135px 0 0 -210px;border-width: medium medium 71px;}
    #ptechsolinside {background-color:#FFF;}
        #ptechsolinside { border-width: medium medium 71px; border-style: none; border-color: blue; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; border-image: none; margin-top: -4px; width: 500px; height: 500px; margin-left: 8px;}
            </style>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dycu/4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

some responsive sites with mediaquery

```
http://mediaqueri.es/
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 319px)  {}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)  {}
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)  {}
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 959px)  {}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DMFuz/1/)**

Here I have just set  below media query, then you have to write others like this

@media screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 480px)  {}

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries.

Here is the [Link](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) that will help you understand all the things about it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try twitter bootstrap.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/